# error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type “std::string”

Tags: c++, string, io, operators

Code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string.h>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
        {
            ifstream fin ("ride.in.txt");
            ofstream fout ("ride.out.txt");
            int ta, tb;unsigned int i;
            ta = tb = 1;
            string a, b;
            fin >> a >> b;
            for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
                ta = ta * (a[i] - 'A' + 1) % 47;
            for (i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
                tb = tb * (b[i] - 'A' + 1) % 47;
            if (ta == tb)
                fout << "GO" << endl;
            else    
                fout << "STAY" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
```

Error:

```
error C2679: 
binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type  “std::string”
```

Comment: There is no question, and the code compiles (when removing the not-provided precompiled header) on clang.

Comment: It will compile on any compiler who's library *happens* to include `<string>` in `<fstream>` or `<iostream>`. One C++ standard header is allowed to include any other standard header.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. It _is_ a real question and there are answers to it. Anyway, there's answers to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1631338/140719).

Answer (score 17):

I think the problem is:

```
#include <string.h>
```

change to:

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `std::string` operators are defined in the `<string>` header.

The header `<string.h>` is for C-style string functions.

Comment: Actually, in C++, the header `<string.h>` doesn't even exist. The content of the C header of that name can be found (wrapped in namespace `std`) in `<cstring>`.

Comment: The header is still part of the C++ standard, even though it is hidden in [Annex D](http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.c.headers#1) (Compatibility features / deprecated).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction!