# Getting error with std::cin>> char*, tried to find similiar problems and using different code, no one has this error

Tags: pointers, char, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* inputFileName = new char;
    cout << "Filename: ";
    cin >> inputFileName;
    cout << inputFileName << endl;
    /* .... */
    delete[] inputFileName;
}
```

Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'char *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

shouldn't this work? Is something wrong with my compiler? using MVS 2018

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631338/error-c2679-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-right-hand-operand-of)

Comment: i saw this, didn't help sadly

Comment: so you're saying you added `#include <string>` and it didn't help right?

Comment: yep, just tested it again with 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>